# How to plot only the last x values of a result?

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm trying to create a predict application.
After I train the network `NARX`,  I can plot the result of outputs with `plotresponse(targets,outputs)`. This command plots the 2000 values that I trained, but I need to display only the last 100 values.
How can I limit the output?

[image: display of 2000 value results]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just select the last 100 values from your data:

```
plotresponse(targets(end-100:end),outputs(end-100:end));
```

I have assumed your data to be vectors, if that's not the case, this may not work. Difficult to say anymore without seeing the code & data used.